# How to Slow Down a WordPress Website

Tags: wordpress, loops, delay

I need to delay the loading time of a WordPress website, to mimic a very slow server. Ideally the delay code should be hidden.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There may be another way to achieve your aim.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do:

either add `sleep(5);` somewhere in the code to completely prevent Wordpress from responding for 5 seconds, or open your site in Firefox browser, press `CTRL+SHIFT+M` to open up your site in a mobile version where you can emulate the connection speed and set the GRPS connection to slow down page load as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found, bandwidth limiting via hosting interface. Thank you.